# How to navigate to sibling pages of NavController child pages?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an `ion-list` with items that leads to:

- Child Page A
- Child Page B
- Child Page C

When on Child Page B, I want to navigate to previous (Child Page A) and next (Child Page C) pages, while maintaining the back button to go back to the parent page.

An example of this would be Mail app in iOS. When you are viewing a mail, it gives you up and down arrows to move to previous/next mail.

I couldn't find anything in the docs that describes this behavior.

**Note this is tagged for ionic2**

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem today and solved it doing this:

```
// Push the sibling page onto the stack. 
this.navCtrl.push( PageToPush, { fooParam : 'bar' } ).then( ()=> {
    // There should be 3 pages in the stack now, and we need to remove the 2nd page (index 1)
    this.navCtrl.remove(1);
}
```

where `this.navCtrl` is an instance of `NavController`. This is assuming that you are always navigating from the root page and want to keep only one child page in the stack. What this is doing is pushing the new page onto the stack (which would be index 2 in the stack) then once the page has been pushed, remove the index 1 page from the stack.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This Child nav-bar

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-light">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <i class="button button-clear button-positive icon ion-android-arrow-back" ng-click="goParent();"></i>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-positive button-clear icon ion-arrow-up-b" ng-click="goPrevious()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
        <button type="submit"class="button button-positive button-clear icon ion-arrow-down-b" ng-click="goNext()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

This app.js

```
  .state('parent', {
    url: '/parent',
    templateUrl: 'templates/parent.html',
    controller: 'ParentCtrl'
  })

  .state('parent-child', {
    url: '/parent/child/:mailSerialNumber',
    templateUrl: 'templates/parent-child.html',
    controller: 'ChildCtrl'
  })
```

This controller.js

```
.controller('ChildCtrl', function ($stateParams, $location, $scope) {

  $scope.URL = {};
  $scope.URL.Parent = "parent"

  $scope.goParent = function () {
      $location.url($scope.URL.Parent);
  };

  $scope.Previous = $stateParams.mailSerialNumber - 1;
  $scope.URL.Previous  = "parent/child/" + $scope.Previous;


  $scope.goPrevious = function () {
      $location.url($scope.URL.Previous);
  };

  $scope.Next = $stateParams.mailSerialNumber + 1;
  $scope.URL.Next = "parent/child/" + $scope.Next;

  $scope.goNext = function () {
      $location.url($scope.URL.Next);
  };

})
```

Comment: Thanks. But question is for ionic 2.